# Can Ubuntu be downloaded to a phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone

I'm not that savvy when it comes to computers but am good on a phone. Can Ubuntu be installed onto a phone?

Comment: Please be aware that installing Ubuntu Touch on your phone will replace EVERYTHING on your phone, including its operating system, and it may not work the way you expect. (It doesn't work at all on most phones.) Make sure you have a plan and method for returning your phone to its original operating system. Also make sure you have **everything** on your phone backed up, including contacts, apps, music, photos, etc. before attempting to install a new operating system. If you are not computer-savvy, this might not be the right project for you.

Comment: "Can Ubuntu be downloaded to a phone?" Yes. "Can Ubuntu be installed onto a phone?" Not without corresponding firmware.

Comment: Depends which phone you have; have a look here: https://ubports.com/

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is no. While there is an Ubuntu variant that works on phones and tablets, called Ubuntu Touch, you cannot just download Ubuntu Touch and install it on your phone as you would install a regular Ubuntu desktop on a computer.

If you are highly tech savvy you may be able to install it on a very limited number of supported phones, and there are now some phones preinstalled with Ubuntu Touch. For somebody who claims to be "not that savvy when it comes to computers", installing it themselves is pretty much completely out, and I wouldn't recommend getting a preinstalled Ubuntu phone either (at this point) unless you are very familiar with Ubuntu and want to tinker with it.

If you are still interested, you can get more information on the [Ubuntu Touch Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch).

Comment: @BrianSilvey If "I am good on a phone" means that you have extensive experience rooting your phone and flashing alternative ROMs (and you happen to have a compatible phone) then go right ahead, of course.

Answer (score -2):

The short answer to your question is yes. In the form of Ubuntu touch. Have a search on google and you will be able to find the link to download  it and install it. I have this on both my new phone and tablet. You can now buy phones and tablet with just Ubuntu on them. Still new but showing promise. The good thing is is that when you connect a blue  tooth  mouse and keyboard and HDMI monitor your phone or tablet turns into a desktop.

Comment: 1 answer edited twice and 4 poinys removed. Very clever

Comment: While not entirely technically wrong, this answer is highly misleading to the point of being clearly wrong in the context of the question. You cannot just download Ubuntu Touch and install it on your phone. If you are highly tech savvy you may be able to install it on a very limited number of supported phones, or there are some phones preinstalled with Ubuntu Touch. For somebody who claims to be "not that savvy when it comes to computers", installing it themselves is completely out, and I wouldn't recommend getting a preinstalled Ubuntu phone either.

Comment: Who has claimed to not be tech savvy? We are here to provide as much help as possible and recommending people not to buy pre-installed ubuntu phones is short sighted and dangerious to the success of the os.

Comment: Typo I know who said they are not savvy

Comment: I absolutely stand by my point that somebody who is not savvy with computers and familiar with Ubuntu should not get an Ubuntu phone until the platform has matured a lot more. Having clueless users be frustrated with the experience does nothing to help the success of the OS.